# Is an object(instance of some class)'s method the same as the instance methods of its class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

After finishing the chapter "The Object Model" in Metaprogramming Ruby, I got confused.
Is an object(instance of some class)'s method the same as the instance methods of its class in Ruby?
It sounds true. because we know the object's methods stored in its class.

```
class W;end

W.methods == Class.instance_methods # => true

# Also

String.instance_methods == "abc".methods # => true
```

`W` is an instance of `Class`. but if I reopen `W` and define a new method for it, than make confuse.

```
class W
  def self.foo
     "bar"
  end
end

W.methods == Class.instance_methods  # => false
```

`W` is a instance of `Class`, and `W`'s methods is `Class`'s instance method. but if `:foo` didn't get stored in `Class`, than where is it stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `wtf` is stored inside the `W` class, not in Ruby's `Class` class.

Think of it as inheritance, when you define a method in the inheriting class it is not available in the inherited class. Likewise, when you define a method in the `W` class it is not available in the `Class` class.
You do not affect the inherited class when you add a method in the inheriting class.

Although I do not recommend messing with Ruby's internal Class class, you can add methods to it by monkey patching it:

```
class Class
  def self.wtf
     "wtf"
  end
end
```

Now `Class.methods.grep /wtf/` will return you the added method.

Comment: -1. This is wrong. `wtf` is not stored inside the `W` class, it is stored inside the `W` class object's singleton class.

Comment: I think I misunderstanding the object and class,Now I get this, `W` is a object of _Class_ and `Class` also a object of _Class_. They are different object. They have same methods  because they are _Class_'s object, if I adding a method to W, It add to W class object's singleton class as @JörgWMittag said. and this type of method is singleton methods. I have just found that In ruby we can define a method like `def obj.method;end`.